# Nullable indexer param for getter only

Tags: c#

I'm having a `Field<T>` class which takes an `Entity` as indexer parameter:

```
class Entity { ... }

class Field<T>
{
    T this[Entity? entity]
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }
        set
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The indexer getter should allow null `Entity` value, whereas the setter shouldn't, as demonstrated as following (unfortunately it does not compile):

```
class Field<T>
{
    T this[Entity? entity] { get... }
    T this[Entity entity] { set... }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Alternatively, use get-only property and a Set method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do in your example code. You defined `Entity` as a class, which makes it a reference type. You can indicate to the compiler it is a nullable reference type, but internally the type is the same. This is different from value types, which become different with the `?`. (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). )

So `Entity` is the same type as `Entity?`, but `int` -> `System.Int32` while `int?` -> `System.Nullable<System.Int32>`.

That's important to note, because of the way indexers are defined. The C# spec says

> The *formal_parameter_list* of an indexer defines the signature (§7.6) of the indexer. Specifically, the signature of an indexer consists of the number and types of its formal parameters. The element type and names of the formal parameters are not part of an indexer’s signature.
>
> [Section 14.9 Indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#149-indexers)

Your code

```cs
T this[Entity? entity] { get... }
T this[Entity entity] { set... }
```

gives a compile error because both signatures are the same.

You can address this in various ways, with varying trade offs. You can always allow null and put in runtime checks to throw exceptions. You can drop one or both of the setter and getter and explicitly implement those as method calls (so you will lose `obj[index]` syntax). You can change the `Entity` to a value type and implement two different indexers with the different type signatures; example of this below.

```cs
namespace IndexerExample
{
    public struct Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Field<T>
    {
        private Dictionary<Entity, T> _values = new Dictionary<Entity, T>();

        public T this[Entity? e]
        {
            get
            {
                if (!e.HasValue)
                {
                    return default(T);
                }

                return _values[e.Value];
            }
        }

        public T this[Entity e]
        {
            get
            {
                return _values[e];
            }

            set
            {
                if (_values.ContainsKey(e))
                {
                    _values[e] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    _values.Add(e, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var f = new Field<int>();
            var e = new Entity() { Id = 3 };

            f[e] = 9;
            var x = f[null];
            var y = f[e];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my sample code in the question. The current implementation allows null and put in runtime checks to throw exception. `Entity` is a class, it cannot be a struct, IMO it's not worth introducing a new struct type to wrap the `Entity` class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for indexers. Try this:

```
public T this[Entity? entity]
{
    get
    {
        return this[entity];
    }
    set
    {
        // check for not null
        this[entity] = value;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Got your point, thanks. This is how I currently handle it. BTW, your code will end up with StackOverflow exception because both getter/setter are calling themselves.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#preconditions-allownull-and-disallownull):

```
[DisallowNull]
public string? ReviewComment
{
    get => _comment;
    set => _comment = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value), "Cannot set to null");
}
string? _comment;
```

> In a nullable context, the ReviewComment get accessor could return the default value of null. The compiler warns that it must be checked before access. Furthermore, it warns callers that, even though it could be null, callers shouldn't explicitly set it to null. The DisallowNull attribute also specifies a pre-condition, it doesn't affect the get accessor. You use the DisallowNull attribute when you observe these characteristics about:

> The variable could be null in core scenarios, often when first instantiated.
> The variable shouldn't be explicitly set to null.

You can undoubtedly adapt your indexer to this.

Comment: The `[DisallowNull]` attribute affects the return/set value of the indexer, not the parameter of the indexer. The attribute should be applied to the parameter, not the indexer, however, there is only one param definition for both indexer getter and setter.